# Bundle package unable to find installed gem

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am trying to bundle and package for two platforms (ruby-2.3.7 and jruby-9.1.17.0)

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'pg_array_parser', git: 'https://github.com/kares/pg_array_parser'
```

These are the commands I issue:

```
rm -rf vendor Gemfile.lock .bundle

rvm use jruby-9.1.17.0
bundle

rvm use 2.3.7
bundle
bundle lock --add_platform java
bundle package --all --all-platforms
```

Everything works fine until the last line (`bundle package --all --all-platforms`).

I expect the last command to work and vendor the `pg_array_parser` gem for both platforms. Instead this is what I am getting:

```
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using pg_array_parser 0.0.9 from https://github.com/kares/pg_array_parser (at master@bad0cad)
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Updating files in vendor/cache
Could not find pg_array_parser-0.0.9-java in any of the sources
```

This looks like a bug in bundler to me. Or am I missing anything?

---

This is the output of `bundle env`:

### Environment

```
Bundler             1.16.2
  Platforms         ruby, x86_64-darwin-17
Ruby                2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [x86_64-darwin17]
  Full Path         /Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby
  Config Dir        /Users/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.7/etc
RubyGems            2.7.7
  Gem Home          /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7
  Gem Path          /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7:/Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@global
  User Path         /Users/alexander/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  Bin Dir           /Users/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/bin
Tools
  Git               2.17.1
  RVM               1.29.3 (master)
  rbenv             not installed
  chruby            not installed
  rubygems-bundler  (1.4.4)
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2018-06-29
Git SHA
Released Version  false
```

### Bundler settings

```
specific_platform
  Set for the current user (/Users/alexander/.bundle/config): true
cache_all_platforms
  Set for your local app (/Users/alexander/projects/test/.bundle/config): true
cache_all
  Set for your local app (/Users/alexander/projects/test/.bundle/config): true
```

### Gemfile

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg_array_parser', git: 'https://github.com/kares/pg_array_parser'
```

#### Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/kares/pg_array_parser
  revision: bad0cad48b70ec9a6e4f67452384d4f72813b646
  specs:
    pg_array_parser (0.0.9)
    pg_array_parser (0.0.9-java)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:

PLATFORMS
  java
  ruby
  universal-java-1.8
  x86_64-darwin-17

DEPENDENCIES
  pg_array_parser!

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.2
```

Comment: What happens if you add `--full-index` flag to the bundle command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.  The most probable place is bundler.  The probably did not update it to the latest versions.

If I use a tad older versions of `MRI ruby-2.3.4` and `jruby-9.1.13.0` it works (on CentOS 7.x):

Here is the log for the `bundle lock --add_platform java`:

```
[smalltalk@localhost so]$ bundle package --all --all-platforms
Writing lockfile to /home/smalltalk/build/so/Gemfile.lock
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using pg_array_parser 0.0.9 from https://github.com/kares/pg_array_parser (at master@bad0cad)
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Updating files in vendor/cache
```

Notice that there is no error - `Could not find pg_array_parser-0.0.9-java in any of the sources`.

Even the `tree` output looks fine to me:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
└── vendor
    └── cache
        └── pg_array_parser-bad0cad48b70
            ├── CHANGELOG.md
            ├── ext
            │   └── pg_array_parser
            │       ├── extconf.rb
            │       ├── pg_array_parser.c
            │       ├── PgArrayParserEngine.java
            │       └── PgArrayParserEngineService.java
            ├── Gemfile
            ├── lib
            │   ├── pg_array_parser
            │   │   └── version.rb
            │   ├── pg_array_parser.jar
            │   └── pg_array_parser.rb
            ├── pg_array_parser.gemspec
            ├── Rakefile
            ├── README.md
            └── spec
                ├── parser_spec.rb
                └── spec_helper.rb

8 directories, 16 files
```

Using older versions appears to work.   Can you do so?